# how to replace value in json array with php

Tags: php, json

i want to replace "created_at" by passing to a function.here is my function

```
 public function getfeeds($showvalue){
      $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id,image,title,status,profilepic,created_at,url FROM news ORDER BY id DESC ");
      $stmt->bind_param("s",$showvalue);
      $stmt->execute();
      $result = $stmt->get_result();

      $nrow = array();
    while ($r = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

       $nrow[] = $r;
    }
       $frow['news'] = $nrow;
    $json = str_replace("\\/", "/",json_encode($frow));
    return $json;

   }
```

i want to replace value created at by passing to a function `converttime($time)`

my convert time function

```
function converttime($time, $full = false) {
    $now = new DateTime;
    $ago = new DateTime($time);
    $diff = $now->diff($ago);

    $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
    $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

    $string = array(
        'y' => 'year',
        'm' => 'month',
        'w' => 'week',
        'd' => 'day',
        'h' => 'hour',
        'i' => 'minute',
        's' => 'second',
    );
    foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
        if ($diff->$k) {
            $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
        } else {
            unset($string[$k]);
        }
    }

    if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
    return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
}
```

please help me how can i convert it

Comment: So you have a function, and you know the value that you want to pass... so what exactly is the question?  Call the function and pass the desired value to it.  Unrelated to that though, you're attempting to bind a value to your statement, but you don't have any parameters in your query.  That's going to be a problem.

Comment: i want to extract only created_ at from query then pass it to a conversion function,get new value for created and the pass it to for json encode

Answer (score 0):

let's get this straight...

1. Call function in variable:

   ```
   $varofcall = $this->converttime($param);
   ```
2. Use the var

   ```
   public function getfeeds($showvalue){
       $varofcall = $this->converttime(param);
       $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id, image, title, status, profilepic, $varofcall ,url FROM news ORDER BY id DESC ");
   ```

Its this ?

Comment: how can i pass the the value to convert time before selecting value from query

Comment: first i want to get value from sql query and pass that value to function and get new value

Comment: Entendi acho que deve fazer isso depois do $ stmt = $ this-> con-> prepare

Comment: I got think I should do this after the $ stmt = $ this-> con-> prepare

Comment: $nrow = array(); after this